# How to prevent a null Delegate?

Tags: c#

I've been searching stackoverflow and other sites for two days trying to figure out why I'm getting a null delegate.  I hate posting a question that has already been answered but I am lost on this problem.  Please forgive me if this is already somewhere on this site.

My goal is to pass some values from one form to another.  But delPassData is always null.

My main form is Form1 and I am trying to send values to it from another form, formNewThread. Here is the relevant code inside formNewThread:

```
public partial class formNewThread : Form
{
    public delegate void delPassDataEventHandler(string where, string newThd); //declare delegate to communicate with Form1
    public event delPassDataEventHandler delPassData;

    private string newThread;
    private string whereUsed;

    public formNewThread(string whereTo, ComboBox cb)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        whereUsed = whereTo;

        ... removed some code here

    }

    public formNewThread()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newThread = textNewThread.Text;

        ... removed code here

                if (delPassData != null)
                    delPassData(whereUsed, newThread);

                this.Close();

    }
```

The relevant code in Form1 is:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            frmNewThd.delPassData += new formNewThread.delPassDataEventHandler(frmNewThd_delPassData);
            newCsg.delPassData += new NewCsg.delPassDataEventHandler(newCsg_delPassData);

          ... removed code

    }

    void frmNewThd_delPassData(string where, string newThd) //this routine communicates with with delegate in form formNewThread
    {
        if (where == "Lnr1")
        {
            comboLinerThread.Text = newThd;
        }
        else if (where == "Body")
        {
            comboBodyThdDown.Text = newThd;
        }
        else if (where == "SetTool")
        {
            comboSetToolThd.Text = newThd;
        }
    }
```

Here's the simple model that I tested and used to implement the delegates you see in the first program above.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace SendDataWithDelegate
  {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    private Form3 frm3 = new Form3();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        frm2.delPassData += new Form2.delPassDataEventHandler(frm2_delPassData); //declaring a new event handler for Form2
        frm3.delPassData += new Form3.delPassDataEventHandler(frm3_delPassData); //declaring a new event handler for Form3
    }

    void frm3_delPassData(double od, double id, double length, double yield) //this routine communicates with delegate in Form3
    {
        labelOD.Text = String.Format("{0:F3}", od);
        labelID.Text = String.Format("{0:F3}", id);
        labelLength.Text = String.Format("{0:F3}", length);
        labelYield.Text = String.Format("{0:N0}", yield);
    }

    void frm2_delPassData(string city, string state) //this routine communicates with delegate in Form2
    {
        labelCity.Text = city;
        labelState.Text = state;
    }

    private void buttonOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //launch Form2
    {
        frm2.Show();
    }

    private void buttonOpenForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //launch Form3
    {
        frm3.Show();
    }
}
```

}

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace SendDataWithDelegate
  {
      public partial class Form2 : Form
      {
          public delegate void delPassDataEventHandler(string city, string state); //declare a delegate to communicate with Form1
          public event delPassDataEventHandler delPassData; //declare an event name for the delegate's event handler

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (delPassData != null)
            delPassData(textCity.Text, textState.Text); //executes if the "delPassData event" occurrs 
    }
}
```

}

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace SendDataWithDelegate
  {
  public partial class Form3 : Form
  {
    public delegate void delPassDataEventHandler(double od, double id, double length, double yield); //declare a delegate to communicate with Form1
    public event delPassDataEventHandler delPassData; //declare an event name for the delegate's event handler

    double ODia;
    double IDia;
    double Len;
    double Sy;

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ODia = Convert.ToDouble(textOD.Text);
        IDia = Convert.ToDouble(textID.Text);
        Len = Convert.ToDouble(textLength.Text);
        Sy = Convert.ToDouble(textYield.Text);

        if (delPassData != null)
            delPassData(ODia, IDia, Len, Sy); //executes if the "delPassData event" occurrs 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can initialize your event as `public event delPassDataEventHandler delPassData = delegate {};`

Comment: @MukeshRawat That's a rather harsh solution. If there is no event to raise, why raise it at all and slow down an application?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Calling a method with no body is a pretty darn fast operation.  On the order of checking something for `null`, in fact.

Comment: @Servy Ok, but I still find it a pretty dumb solution.

Comment: Bob, can you proivide a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem at hand.  As it is you have a lot of code that's not actually relevant to replicating the problem, and it'd be much easier to sort through if you were able to remove what code isn't needed to replicate the problem.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Why is that?  I consider it unfortunate that delegate fields are `null` until an event handler is added to them in the first place, but adding an empty handler isn't a terrible workaround to such an unfortunate situation.

Comment: I know, this program is huge.  I'll remove some of it.

Comment: Side note, why are you using `ArrayList`?  You should almost certainly be using `List` instead.

Comment: What's with the camel case class name too?

Comment: @Servy Because it won't solve the problem entirely. There's still a chance that you accidentally remove that empty action and there you go ...

Comment: It seems the only way it could be null is if this publishButton is getting clicked before Form1's constructor binds the event handler, or if some other, unseen portion of code is unbinding the event handler.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek That can only be done from within the definition of the class though; it's not something that can be done externally.  It's also not a sensible thing to do, so the risk of this is both very low, and easily located in the event of a problem.  Dealing with race conditions involving the delegate being null when invoked on the other hand is a *very* hard problem to solve, and results in hard to diagnose code when the race conditions poke their head up.

Comment: Are you sure that the form you're adding an event handler to is the form that you're clicking the button for?

Comment: Yes, I've triple checked to make sure the event handler is connected to the correct form.  What is confusing is that I wrote a tiny program that does this and I modeled this big program like it.  The little program works fine but the big program is setting delPassData to null.

Comment: I'll add the small program that I modeled after so you can see how it works.

Comment: @BobT Then clearly your minimal reproduction is missing something.  Continue adding back in parts of the main application until you can replicate the problem.  Or, what may be more effective, is to start back over with a copy of the main application and continue removing pieces until you can no longer replicate the problem.  When you have nothing left to remove that doesn't remove the error, you're left with your minimal repo.

Comment: Thanks @Servy, that's a good technique.  What confuses me is why would the delegate go null???

Comment: @BobT My money is still on [you having the wrong form instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708514/how-to-prevent-a-null-delegate?noredirect=1#comment32824760_21708514) as the most likely option.  There isn't enough code shown to know if that's actually the case though

Comment: Thanks @Servy, I'll go through it carefully to make sure.

Comment: @MukeshRawat I tried your suggestion "public event delPassDataEventHandler delPassData = delegate {};"  It prevented the null condition and the values to be passed were there!  But as was mentioned, it appears the receiving instance "frmNewThd_delPassData" is not being executed!  I've checked and the instances are correct!?!?!

Comment: I checked all the instances for the delegate and they are correct.  I'm going to abandon this approach and go back to setting up separate classes and use a ValueUpdateEVentArg.